# Azure offline sync update table without using SDK apis

Tags: android, azure

I have following requirement in my android app,

I would like to access the local store db directly and modify the records, and i would like to sync this data automatically using offline sync supported by azure.
Microsoft provides api to get local db access using apis such as getReadableDatabase(), getWritableDatabase() and allows us to execute the statements directly on local store db. But when i see SDK's sync table apis code in MobileServiceSyncTable it looks like it keeps track of each operation and then sends it to server. 
So, my question is

1. is it really possible to execute the statements and sync it using SDK itself? If not then why MS is providing api to access the local db?
2. Suppose i update the db, using raw sql queries, will it sync atleast after the application restarted? i think it would be possible because M.S would lose the track of changes if app is restarted before sync and it must compare the table and sync it again after restart. Am i right?

Comment: @Downvoter, whats wrong with the question?

Comment: too broad, too many questions

Comment: @amdixon I removed few, even though i am sure that in discussion later it may popup again. So question still needs improvement?